# How to remove/add/replace numbers from multiple filenames?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, rename, batch-rename

How to remove and add numbers from multiple filenames?

For example, I want to change the names of filenames `Apple1.sh` and  `Banana2.sh` to `Apple.sh` and `Banana.sh`

I have googled this for a while but I haven't found a precise answer

Found this:

```
for i in *.sh; do
  echo "$i" | sed 's/^[0-9_ ]*//'
done
```

But it only displays the output and doesn't change the filenames.

I also need to add numbers, for example, 3 to the renamed filenames so they become `Apple3.sh` and `Banana3.sh` still can't find ways to do this.

Bulk renaming that only changes numbers could be helpful too. Like from `Apple3.sh` and `Banana3.sh` to `Apple4.sh` and `Banana4.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Perl-based `rename` command (available by installing the [rename package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/rename)), ex.:

- replace a non-empty sequence of digits before a period with nothing

  ```
  $ rename -n 's/(\d+)(?=\.)//' *.sh
  rename(Apple1.sh, Apple.sh)
  rename(Banana2.sh, Banana.sh)
  ```
- increment a non-empty sequence of digits before a period

  ```
  $ rename -n 's/(\d+)(?=\.)/$1+2/e' *.sh
  rename(Apple1.sh, Apple3.sh)
  rename(Banana2.sh, Banana4.sh)
  ```

The `-n` option is for testing - remove it when you want to actually rename the files.

Comment: @Raffa thanks, don't know how I missed that - I had the escape originally, then decided to use a lookahead, and forgot to carry it over

Comment: You're most welcome ... I knew it was a typo, so I fixed it right away ... Nice use of a lookahead positive in the right place BTW ... I don't see these used enough recently :-)